# Citroen C2 Catalytic converter replaced with patches

Tags: catalytic-converter, citroen

I just had a new catalytic converter fixed by a local mechanic and there are few patches visible. Wondering if this is sloppy work and might cause issues soon. Could any one help me understand if this is an issue of concern? [image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That just looks like a paper sticker to me.  Probably just had the manufacturers part number on it.

It will probably just drop off soon.  (Not the exhaust).

When the exhaust is cold, try peeling it off.  Probably best, just in case it ignites due to the heat.